# In Windows Chrome, how can I reduce mouse speed when pressing mouse wheel and moving the mouse up or down?

Tags: mouse, scrolling

In Windows Chrome,  how can I reduce mouse speed when pressing mouse wheel down and tilting the mouse up or down? If you do this in Mozilla there seems to be more speedlevels with which you can scroll the sites. I'd like to have it on Chrome as well.

Regards,
Rafal

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Google Chrome.

There, scrolling speed when scrolling with the mouse wheel pressed is determined by how far your mouse pointer is moved away from the original point where you pressed down the mouse wheel.

So if you want to scroll slowly, keep your pointer close to where you first pressed the mouse wheel.

If you want to scroll fast, move your pointer away further from the original point.